# Animate a canvas programatically using StoryBoard API in Windows Store App

Tags: xaml, storyboard, windows-store-apps

I am animating a canvas in a Windows Store app using StoryBoard API:

```
        DoubleAnimation widthAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        DoubleAnimation heightAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

        widthAnimation.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, outDuration + inDuration);
        heightAnimation.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, outDuration + inDuration);
        widthAnimation.Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, collapseDuration);
        heightAnimation.Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, collapseDuration);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(widthAnimation, target);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(widthAnimation, "Width");
        Storyboard.SetTarget(heightAnimation, target);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(heightAnimation, "Height");

        widthAnimation.From = beginSize.Width;
        widthAnimation.To = endSize.Width;
        heightAnimation.From = beginSize.Height;
        heightAnimation.To = endSize.Height;

        Storyboard stb = new Storyboard();
        stb.Children.Add(widthAnimation);
        stb.Children.Add(heightAnimation);

        stb.Begin();
```

However the width and height animation does not work. Any pointers on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue using a related post in MSDN forums - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/e660077c-1a8f-463c-a118-ebb4de008176/

Width and Height are dependent animations and hence it must be enabled explicitly using the following code:

```
    widthAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
    heightAnimation.EnableDependentAnimation = true;
```